# Firefox focus bug

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, razor, focus

I'm using a focus event for saving value of input before changing.

```
onfocus="saveTemp(this);"
```

And in saveTemp

```
function saveTemp(item)
{
    tempVal = item.value;
}
```

Nothing special...

In my chrome 49.0.2623.112 m (64-bit) works everything perfect. Click with my mouse at input, it saves the value. But with Firefox it has bugs.

When I click in Firefox directly at number in input, it focuses fine. But when I click on another input in padding area immediately right after previous click, it calls focus event on previous input. So it saves a value of different input.

Next thing I realize is that after clean page load when i click in padding of input, it calls onchange event in Firefox.

I have Firefox 46.0.1

Is it a bug or a feature? How can I against it?

EDIT:

As I said, code is nothing special in spite of I generate JS code in Razor View and HTML in WebGrid. idPrefix is used due to multiple tabs in page as something like namespace.

```
new WebGridColumn{
    Header="Price",
    Format = @<text>
        <input type="number" id="@(Model.idPrefix + "InPrice_" + item.pk_id)" value="@item.price" placeholder="Price" onfocus="@(Model.idPrefix)saveTemp(this);" onchange="@(Model.idPrefix)reSum1(this);" />
    </text>
},
```

And JS code

```
var @(Model.idPrefix)oldPrice;
function @(Model.idPrefix + "reSum1")(item)
{
    if(item.value == "")
        item.value = 0;
    if(@(Model.idPrefix + "oldPrice") == "")
        @(Model.idPrefix + "oldPrice") = 0;
    $("#@(Model.idPrefix)LblSumPrice")[0].innerHTML = parseFloat($("#@(Model.idPrefix)LblSumPrice")[0].innerHTML) - parseFloat(@(Model.idPrefix + "oldPrice")) + parseFloat(item.value);

    @(Model.idPrefix + "oldPrice") = item.value;
}

function @(Model.idPrefix + "saveTemp")(item)
{
    @(Model.idPrefix + "oldPrice") = item.value;
}
```

Generated column:

```
<td>
    <input type="number" id="INV_InPrice_4194" value="0" placeholder="Price" onfocus="INV_saveTemp(this);" onchange="INV_reSum1(this);">               
</td>
```

Generated functions:

```
var INV_oldPrice;
function INV_saveTemp(item)
{
    INV_oldPrice = item.value;
}

function INV_reSum1(item)
{
    if(item.value == "")
        item.value = 0;
    if(INV_oldPrice == "")
        INV_oldPrice = 0;
    $("#INV_LblSumPrice")[0].innerHTML = parseFloat($("#INV_LblSumPrice")[0].innerHTML) - parseFloat(INV_oldPrice) + parseFloat(item.value);

    INV_oldPrice = item.value;
}
```

All code generated fine and works correctly in chrome as I said. IE can't find generated JS function, but it is probably for different topic.

Comment: do you have a code sample?

Comment: Code included, any ideas? I think, it's a browser's feature...

Comment: Actually, focus gets triggered twice, but on the correct element. Is my fiddle correct set up? https://jsfiddle.net/ud30gxuy/

Comment: It's a correct fiddle. You can see wrong behaviour when you click on left input right next to number and then when you click in padding of right input. Console prints this:  
FOCUS - id: INV_InPrice_4194 value: 0  
CHANGE - id: INV_InPrice_4195 value: 0  
FOCUS - id: INV_InPrice_4195 value: 0  
But it should be:  
FOCUS - id: INV_InPrice_4194 value: 0  
CHANGE - id: INV_InPrice_4194 value: 0  
FOCUS - id: INV_InPrice_4195 value: 0

Comment: change event should only occur on blur and the input value has changed, not if you only focus/blur without changing. But indeed the change event should not trigger on the second input. Note that the behavior is correct when you change to input type="text"

Comment: Perhaps you should change the logic to save value onblur, or use oninput. But they require rethinking your logic. Also, instead of storing oldprice, you could store old input id, allowing you to compare with current id to work around the bug. Then get its value if needed. Of course the simplest workaround is to not have any padding.

Comment: Thanks for tips! Storing old input ids sounds interesting. Disabling padding is in case of input is a right way, i hope some day all browsers will work on the same line... - joke, it will never happen